# cross platform checksum for c#,java and objective c

Tags: c#, java, objective-c

I'm looking for a checksum code/lib that will give me the same results in .net , android and ios.

for now trying to implements algos from the web or using diffrent libraries that suppouse to give same results failed

anyone got something that works ?

Comment: If this is used against random corruption (a.o.t an attacker) the MD5 implementations in all 3 will be compatible and should suffice.

Answer (score 3):

checksum building is language agnostic.

md5 will be md5

sha512 will be sha512

=> dont look for a 'cross-platform' lib

Answer (score 1):

Given the simplicty of building a check sum (if it doesn't have to be secure), I would write in all three languages yourself.

It could be this kind of thinking which makes it hard to find three implementations which happen to produce the same result. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try java.util.zip.CRC32